# Can't push files to device

Tags: android, adb, selinux

I am using `adb` to push and pull files to and from an android device.
Those files are configs and data for our app, that is installed and used on a restricted user account.

There is a special exchange folder in the device-users home directory.
A typical folder layout (for android 6+) is as follows:

```
/storage/emulated/0             // home dir of main device user

/storage/emulated/10            // home dir of restricted user
/storage/emulated/10/exchange   // our file exchange dir
```

Recently we discovered that file exchange is not working on a `Samsung Galaxy Tab S` running Android 6.0.1.

```
// Pushing to main user works just fine
$ ./adb push barfoo.txt /storage/emulated/0
[   ?] /storage/emulated/0/barfoo.txt: 0/?

// Pushing to restricted user does not work
$ ./adb push barfoo.txt /storage/emulated/10
adb: error: failed to copy 'barfoo.txt' to '/storage/emulated/10/barfoo.txt': Permission denied
```

In the logcat output I found the following clues:

```
audit   : type=1400 msg=audit(1496849979.822:280): avc:  denied  { write } for  pid=15762 comm="adbd" name="10" dev="sdcardfs" ino=130656 scontext=u:r:adbd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:container_app_data_backend:s0:c522,c768 tclass=dir
audit   :  SEPF_SECMOBILE_6.0.1_0021
audit   : type=1300 msg=audit(1496849979.822:280): arch=40000028 syscall=322 per=800008 success=no exit=-13 a0=ffffff9c a1=b6bc0fc8 a2=a00c1 a3=1b6 items=1 ppid=1 ppcomm=init pid=15762 auid=4294967295 uid=2000 gid=2000 euid=2000 suid=2000 fsuid=2000 egid=2000 sgid=2000 fsgid=2000 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="adbd" exe="/sbin/adbd" subj=u:r:adbd:s0 key=(null)
audit   : type=1307 msg=audit(1496849979.822:280):  cwd="/"
audit   : type=1302 msg=audit(1496849979.822:280): item=0 name="/storage/emulated/10/barfoo.txt" inode=130656 dev=00:17 mode=040771 ouid=0 ogid=1015 rdev=00:00 obj=u:object_r:container_app_data_backend:s0:c522,c768
audit   : type=1327 msg=audit(1496849979.822:280): proctitle=2F7362696E2F61646264002D2D726F6F745F7365636C6162656C3D753A723A73753A7330
audit   : type=1320 msg=audit(1496849979.822:280):
```

As far as I understand there are some SELinux policies enforced that prevent me from pushing files.

Is anyone able to reproduce this? Is there a way to loosen the SELinux policies? What would you do to exchange the files?

Comment: Did you try pushing with root?

Comment: How do I do that? `sudo ./adb push ...` does not make any difference. The device itself is not rooted. Is it possiblie to run `adb push` as a specific device user just like calling intents over adb?

Comment: Check Developer options if there is root access option.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately there in no such option in the developer settings. USB Debugging is enabled, debug authorizations were cleared and my machine is authorized. USB mode is set to MTP. The AndroidFileTransfer App for mac enables me to drop files to the desired folders. Maybe we should implement our filetransfer through MTP.

Comment: @lupz I use an adb script to copy files to my device, specifically because my MTP connection seems to stop me copying files half the time.

Answer (score 0):

The files you see through AndroidFileTransfer are actually not in the route you are trying to push.

Give `adb push barfoo.txt sdcard/` a try.

If you do `adb shell` and `cd sdcard`, I bet you can see the same files you see in AndroidFileTransfer. This is because they are actually symbolic links and although you do not have an `sdcard` per se, that's the directory name used.

Comment: Thank you. I'll give it a shot.